# How to create a multi level document using MongoId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am developing a Ruby on Rails (3.2.6) application and is using MongoId (3.0.0) to interact with the MongoDB database. I am just wondering how do save embeded JSON objects that contains multiple levels and not just one level.

I got an old MongoDB database with this and simular structure so I need to save new documents using the same structure.

*This is from the documentation and is used to add a one level document:*

```
Person.create(
  first_name: "Heinrich",
  last_name: "Heine"
)
```

*How can I add an object with this structure:*

```
{
    "basic": {
        "file_id": {
            "file": "cf1952761a806c56c9bee60665418f02c"
        },
        "share": false,
        "status": "created"
    },
    "data": {
        "id": "4fd942dder5f5e88837300026e",
        "name": "roberta",
        "comment": "This is a comment"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create classes for `basic` and `data` and embed them in your top level document.

Embedded document classes are defined in Mongoid the same way as other documents with an `embedded_in` call and a matching `embeds_one` or `embeds_many` in the top level document.

The other option is to simply define a Hash field, but this obviously may have any structure.

```
Class Person
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :data, :type => Hash

    ...
end
```

`:data` will accept any hash, even with nested hashes.

Comment: Ah ok. Basically what I need is to be able to control how data is saved (hierarchy/structure) in a document. Creating a class for basic and data seems to be overkill since they are only there to provide a hierarchy. Is it possible that you could you show me an example how to use your second option (Hash field)? Very thankful!

Comment: I think it is fine to have those small classes, especially if you are trying to impose structure on your data. A hash does not enforce any structure.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I only need to use models for them, not controllers?

Comment: That's right, embedded objects don't need there own controllers, it is possible, and easy, to interact with them entirely from the parent controller.

Comment: Whether you have Hash fields named `basic` and `data` or the relevant embedded objects, you will be able to save that JSON automatically.